# Getting integer data from txt file in Java

Tags: java, file-io, arraylist

I want to read a text file which has String and a few integers related to that string.

This is the class that I have to write my program in:

```
public List<Integer> Data(String name) throws IOException {
    return null;
}
```

I have to read the .txt file and find the name in that file, with its data. And save it in an `ArrayList`.

My question is how do I save it in the `ArrayList<Integer>` when I have `String`s in the `List`.
This is what I think I would do:

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(filename));
ArrayList<Integer> data = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while (s.hasNextLine()) {
    data.add(s.nextInt());
}
s.close();
```

Comment: You want to turn String to integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define the file as a field (in addition to the `filename`, and I suggest reading it from the user's home folder) `file`

```
private File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), filename);
```

Then you can use the diamond operator `<>` when you define your `List`. You can use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close` your `Scanner`. You want to read by lines. And you can `split` your `line`. Then you test if your first column matches the name. If it does, iterate the other columns are parse them to `int`. Something like

```
public List<Integer> loadDataFor(String name) throws IOException {
    List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] row = s.nextLine().split("\\s+");
            if (row[0].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                for (int i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
                    data.add(Integer.parseInt(row[i]));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

It might be signifanctly more efficient to scan the file once and store the names and fields as a `Map<String, List<Integer>>` like

```
public static Map<String, List<Integer>> readFile(String filename) {
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
    File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), filename);
    try (Scanner s = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] row = s.nextLine().split("\\s+");
            List<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
                al.add(Integer.parseInt(row[i]));
            }
            map.put(row[0], al);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return map;
}
```

Then store that as `fileContents` like

```
private Map<String, List<Integer>> fileContents = readFile(filename);
```

And then implement your `loadDataFor(String)` method with `fileContents` like

```
public List<Integer> loadDataFor(String name) throws IOException {
    return fileContents.get(name);
}
```

If your usage pattern reads the `File` for many names then the second is likely to be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use java8 you could use something like this.

Input.txt (has to be in classpath):

```
text1;4711;4712
text2;42;43
```

The code:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        // find file in classpath
        Path path = Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("input.txt").toURI());

        // find the matching line
        findLineData(path, "text2")

                // print each value as line to the console output
                .forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    /** searches for a line in a textfile and returns the line's data */
    private static IntStream findLineData(Path path, String searchText) throws IOException {

        // securely open the file in a "try" block and read all lines as stream
        try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path)) {
            return lines

                    // split each line by a separator pattern (semicolon in this example)
                    .map(line -> line.split(";"))

                    // find the line, whiches first element matches the search criteria
                    .filter(data -> searchText.equals(data[0]))

                    // foreach match make a stream of all of the items
                    .map(data -> Arrays.stream(data)

                            // skip the first one (the string name)
                            .skip(1)

                            // parse all values from String to int
                            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt))

                    // return one match
                    .findAny().get();
        }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
42
43
```